# How should I fill DS160 while I'm working with a Hong Kong Company?

Tags: visas, usa

I'm Turkish citizen. I'm working in a senior manager in a company that based on Hong Kong.

I'm living in Turkey. Should I write the company's address in Hong Kong to primary occupation fields?

Other than that, this company does not provide worker insurance for me in Turkey because the company is based in Hong Kong, not in TR. However, I have an employment agreement with signature of Global HR Head that I can prove that I am an employee.

Do you think which questions should I pay attention to when filling out the document?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: I'm working remotely.

Comment: Don't know the specifics in Turkey, but in many other countries this would be illegal. Either you are salaried by the company, and all taxes, social security, national insurance, etc. contributions should be declared and paid by the employer, or you are a freelancer, and it's up to you to register, invoice your customer, manage accounts, file and pay taxes, etc. Do you receive pay slips? Do you declare your income? Have you registered as a business? Do you have a business bank account? Do you generate invoices?

Comment: The US may not care if you are working legally or not so this may not be very important, but (to be sure you have the finances to support yourself during your visit and/or to ascertain you are likely to leave the US and return to your home country in time) they will probably ask for bank statements and/or pay slips etc. and if you're not "inside the lines" you may have a hard time providing such evidence and/or they may find it questionable.

Comment: If you're working remotely, what's going to stop you from working while in the US? What will be the forcing factor for you to return to Turkey after your visit?